# How to see files and folder of google drive API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, google-drive-api

I created a google project, and setup all I need to use google drive API with JWT crementials.

It doesn't need any auth2 authentification since it's a server-server communication, user are not involved in the process.

This is working fine but why it's not using my account drive?
If I create a folder or a file, I can"t see it in google drive, so is this using a different storage, and if so, do I have a way to see all my files and folder like a normal google drive account?

I'm using nodeJs and so far this worked :

```
var google = require('googleapis');
var drive = google.drive('v3');
var config = require('../config/config');
var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(config.google.drive.client_email, null, config.google.drive.private_key, ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'], null);

jwtClient.authorize(function(err, tokens) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }

    // Make an authorized request to list Drive files.
    //drive.files.create({
    //    auth: jwtClient,
    //    resource: {
    //        mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
    //        title: 'my new folder'
    //    }
    //},function(err,response){
    //    if(err){
    //        console.log('error at gdrive creat folder: ' + err);
    //    }else{
    //        console.log('create response: ');
    //    }
    //});

    drive.files.list({ auth: jwtClient }, function(err, resp) {
        // handle err and response
        console.log('err', err);
        console.log('resp', resp);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're referring to [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) for the server-to-server interaction.

Its not going in your account since its going to the Service Account's configured user. You can delegate the [domain-wide authority to the Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority) but only if you have Google Apps for Work

Comment: thx for the informations, I found a way to make it work, by creating a folder in my google account and share it with my service account (using the email created for it) and it's working fine.

Comment: @Gatsbill The information in your last comment saved my day ! Not trying to command you in any way, but it would seem a very good idea to me if you would add it to your original question under some "DECENT WORKAROUND FOUND" title :-)